# How to keep timer going when inside navigation link SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, timer, onappear

so I'll keep it simple: I have a timer that runs on appear of this view as follows:

```
struct FocusView: View {

@State var isTimerRunning = false
@State private var startTime =  Date()
@State private var timerString = "0.00"
@State private var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

 var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {
           VStack {
   Text(self.timerString)
                .font(Font.system(.largeTitle, design: .monospaced))
                .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                    if self.isTimerRunning {
                        timerString = String(format: "%.2f",(Date().timeIntervalSince( self.startTime)))
                    }
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    
                    if isTimerRunning {
                        self.stopTimer()
                        soundManager.stopSound()
                        //statee.hideTabView = false
                    } else {
                        
                        timerString = "00.00.00"
                        startTime = Date()
                        self.startTimer()
                        soundManager.playSoundFocus()
                        selected = 3
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                .onAppear() {
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                    
                    if isTimerRunning {
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    else {
                        // no need for UI updates at startup
                        timerString = "00.00.00"
                        startTime = Date()
                        // start UI updates
                        self.startTimer()
                        
                    }
                    }
                }

   func stopTimer() {
    self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
    isTimerRunning = false
   // isMusicPlaying = false
}

func startTimer() {
    self.timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.01, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    isTimerRunning = true
   // isMusicPlaying = true
}
```

Now when I go to some other view via tab view (let's call is view B) the timer still keeps running. BUT, the moment I go inside a navigation link inside view B the timer stops. Does anyone know how can I keep running the timer? I'm not sure if it's a navigation link issue or a tab view issue. Would appreciate any input. Thanks!

Comment: you do not have a `NavigationLink` in your code, that is probably the main problem.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine so I have a Navigation Link in another View. I think I mentioned that in the question. This is FocusView. Navigation Link is in another View  called View B. I hope I was able to explain!

Comment: it was not clear to me at all. Show a minimum reproducible example code, so we can test it and find an answer. The problem you describe is to do with going to the NavigationLink, but you don't show any of that. Is this reasonable?

Comment: Your provided code is a bit confusing.

Comment: Needed minimal reproducible example to debug, but most probably view with timer is just recreated. Separate timer (and dependent logic) into view model and keep it outside of view, injecting corresponding instance into view, so view just show view model state independently of how/when it is created.